# pik not listing ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, pik

I'm running win 7 and just installed pik via the installer. I listed the ruby versions and the most recent version is 1.9.2[-1.3.6]. I saw a post where someone mentioned to use "pik list -r" but pik tells me it's deprecated and then uses "list known" anyway. I want to install ruby 1.9.3 and do not currently have any ruby installed on this machine.

Sorry in advance if this is a duplicate question, but I didn't see it.

Thanks
Patrick

Comment: did you add the ruby 1.9.2 dir to the pik list by doing pik add <path to your ruby installation> ?

Comment: I actually don't have any ruby on this machine, I was shooting to have the manager take care of it all from the beginning. That might be a good workaround though, thank.

Comment: you have to tell pik manually to which directory your different rubies are installed. Its not so smart as RVM !!

Comment: oh really? I like RVM, I use it all the time on my personal machines. I was hoping that it would install it for me and manage the different versions. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

As Raghu said, you need to specify existing ruby installations by

```
pik add <path to ruby executable>
```

However, for getting the latest ruby revision, you can perform the installation like rvm,

just do a pik install like:

```
pik install ruby
```

or

```
pik install jruby
```